# Modify admin password on Magento Enterprise Edition directly on the database

Tags: magento

I've updated a Magento community site to a Magento Enterprise Edition. My problem is that I can't login on the backoffice anymore. Magento EE uses a different password encryption so the old admin password doesn't work. The only way to change it is using a mysql query, but I don't know what's the encryption type. All tutorials I've found focus only on Magento Community.

Thanks for your help.

Pau

Comment: By the way. It is possible to recover the password using the «Forgot your password» link. However, this it's interesting finding out how the enterprise edition encrypts the password...

Answer (score 6):

Put this as the very bottom of your index.php file and you will see the hash to insert into the database:

```
    Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::helper('core')->getHash('password', 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your DB, search the admin_user table. search the row by your username and edit it and make a new passwd and choise the MD5 encryption

Comment: The Enterprise edition doesn't use MD5 encryption (I think that neither do the community edition anymore)...

Comment: As of 1.6 just using MD5 should still work for CE at least and likely for EE as well.